# Change the text of UISwitch

Tags: iphone, uiswitch

I want to change the switch control text YES/NO in place of ON/OFF , i am not know is it possible or not. if its possible and any one know about it please help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think its not possible to change the text of switch in proper way, but every problem has minimum one solution so for your problem you have to create the custom switch control 
for help download the code from

here 
1 : http://www.xprogress.com/post-30-uiswitch-tutorial-example-how-to-use-the-switch-in-xcode-for-iphone-sample-included/

2 : http://www.catamount.com/blog/1063/uicustomswitch-customizing-uiswitch-color-it-change-labels/

3 : help check this also http://www.xprogress.com/post-30-uiswitch-tutorial-example-how-to-use-the-switch-in-xcode-for-iphone-sample-included/

Thanks,
Raj

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to change this two values in easy way.

You can look here: http://www.catamount.com/blog/1063/uicustomswitch-customizing-uiswitch-color-it-change-labels/

but this solution make custom UISwitch which got other graphics

Answer (score 2):

I currently use this open source library called [RCSwitch](http://osiris.laya.com/projects/rcswitch/) . Much more robust than the others mentioned.